# Divide top 3 numbers and leave the rest unchanged

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to divide the top 3 numbers in my dataframe and leave the rest untouched.

I have divided the top 3 values but want to return my dataframe along with the other values that have not been divided

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(3)/2)
```

Comment: pls give us sample data and your expected result. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame.nlargest` requires you to pass a list of columns that will determine "Large-ness"

This should return the top three rows as determined by columns `['col1']`

```
df.nlargest(3, columns=['col1'])
```

You can then use `pandas.DataFrame.update` all in one line

```
df.update(df.nlargest(3, columns=['col1']) / 2)
```

Comment: Could you please correct the typo in the last snippet from df.largest to df.nlargest

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the original dataframe (df) with new values from df2.

```
    df=pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 12, 14, 18])
    df2 = df.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(3)/2)
    df.loc[df.index.isin(df2.index)] = df2
    print(df)
```

Result:

```
       0
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    5.0
5    6.0
6    7.0
7    8.0
8    9.0
9   10.0
10   6.0
11   7.0
12   9.0
```